# how can I get python to append var and dont change it?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import twitter
import unicodedata
import string


def get_tweets(user):

    resultado=[]
    temp=[]
    api=twitter.Api()#   
    statuses=api.GetUserTimeline(user)
    for tweet in statuses:
        var = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', tweet.text).encode('utf-8', 'replace')
        print var# Horóscopo when i dont append it 
        resultado.append(var)
        print resultado# Horo\xcc\x81scopo, mie\xcc\x81rcoles i get these when i append them 


get_tweets('HoroscopoDeHoy')
```

Comment: I can't run that on my machine, so... I don't know what you're looking at.

Comment: Python 2 or 3?  Strings/unicode are different between the two.

Comment: could you also add the line `print resultado[0]` ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to put the unicode into a list:

```
  var = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', tweet.text)
  resultado.append( var )
  temp.append(var.encode('utf-8', 'ignore'))
```

Comment: Its python 2.7. After exeucting these two lines: var = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', tweet.text)
        var.encode('utf-8', 'replace') i get these output Horóscopo and word with accents and i want to append those words with accents in to result but when i append them i get this Horo\xcc\x81scopo how can i append it with accents?

Comment: scratch the comment from above.Its python 2.7. After executing these two lines: var = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', tweet.text).encode('utf-8', 'replace')
        print var and i get these output Horóscopo a word with accents and i want to append those words with accents in to result. but when i execute thes other two statements resultado.append(var)
        print resultado i get this Horo\xcc\x81scopo how can i append it with accents?

Comment: Marco my question that when i convert it to utf-8 i want to keep it like that while appending it.

Comment: I think it is just a matter of displaying. The value is in both cases the same. But when printing resultado it is displayed in a list. What happens if you do `print resultado[0]` ?

Comment: what i want it to do is to return the whole list of results with the accents and that would just print the first one

Comment: But does it look good? do you see the accent if you include `print resultado[0]` after `print resultado` ? Could you test it?

Comment: yeas. it looks good but when i try to return all results i go back and this: Horo\xcc\x81scopo, mie\xcc\x81rcoles 04 de julio de 2012  Consulte que le deparan los astros segu\xcc\x81n su signo para este di\xcc\x81a http://t.co/PjorIt0l', 'Horo\xcc\x81scopo, martes 03 de julio de 2012  Consulte que\xcc\x81 le deparan los astros para hoy, segu\xcc\x81n su signo http://t.co/oHTmYPeq', 'CAPRICORNIO\nLos objetivos se ven ma\xcc\x81s claros y dispone de energi\xcc\x81a para afirmar su posicio\xcc\x81n de liderazgo.', 'SAGITARIO\nLas condiciones ido\xcc\x81neas para utilizar el poder que posee esta]

Comment: So do not worry: your utf-8 strings have not changed. When you print the list your strings are printed as ascii . But they stay the same. It is just how printing a list works in Python 2

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the print command. Print runs string conversion on the list which escapes any "funny" characters before writing them to standard output. If you want to display each item on the same line I would suggest doing:

```
for item in resultado:
   print item,
```

This should bypass the string conversion on the list.

Sources:
http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement 
http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#string-conversions

Comment: As a side note, the value stored in your list should still be a unicode string. The only change that you are seeing is happening when it is displaying. (as Marco de Wit said above)